# ViewPager - get a partial view of the next page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to achieve this in a ViewPager

The first fragment (blue) is displayed and the beginning of the next fragment must be displayed as well, so the user understands he can swipe to switch views.
The idea is scroll 20% of the screen programmatically to the left.

Any thoughts are welcome

**EDIT:** This is exactly what I need to to: the central view needs to overlap both side views

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can try adding this to your PageAdapter:

```
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    if (position == 0 || position == 2) {
        return 0.8f;
    }
    return 1f;
}
```

Comment: @Juizas:I am also facing the same issueIts working fine.Thank you.But I have number of dynamic views for every view i need to show pre and next page, It shwoing only right side child only. I tried it many ways please help on this issue. Like this https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1  but it's taking time to load views

Comment: @Praveena, if getPageWidth() is not working as you need, you may have to look for alternative solution. Maybe use negative value for setPageMargin. Maybe add ViewPager source code to your project and modify it.

Answer (score 15):

Try using a negative value for [ViewPager.setPageMargin](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setPageMargin%28int%29).

Comment: that works but causes the fragments to overlap-- if this is the best fix, then make sure your pages are skinny enough to use it.

Comment: Thanks AdamK, this only partially solves my problem as I need to do a little more than this. I have updated the question, do you have an idea?

Comment: @zylootino - unfortunately I don't think a standard ViewPager is able to accomplish your updated version. You will need to custom build this yourself by extending ViewPager, which will be a more complicated task. I don't have any immediate suggestions for where to start sorry.

Comment: I also set negative value for `ViewPager.setPageMargin`, and also: `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` to pre-loading the next page and avoid flicking effects

Answer (score 13):

This function worked better than the answer marked as correct (for me anyway).

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return 0.9f;
}
```

Just place it in your custom `PagerAdapter` class.

Comment: Refer to the contents of the function - the accepted answer didnt work for me, this one did.

Answer (score 2):

```
viewpager.setClipToPadding(false);
viewpager.setPageMargin(-50);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return 0.9f;
}
```

Use this, this will work perfectly and make sure that your class extended to PagerAdapter