# Facebook style slider

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

the new facebook app has an image slider inside posts which have multiple images. It looks something like this:
 [image]

One thing to notice is the adjacent images are slightly displayed with the current image in focus.

I know I can implement a slider using viewpager. But, in a viewpager, the current fragment occupies the entire view. Only the titles of the adjacent views are visible, not the content itself.

Can anybody give me a direction to look at for implementing this. Or is there anu opensource library for this?

Thanks

Comment: found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907748/viewpager-get-a-partial-view-of-the-next-page

Comment: The only problem is it does not show the left side item, only shows the right side item partially.