# How to replicate Facebook Album Gallery (android)

Tags: android, facebook, gallery

I was wondering how can I replicate the sideways gallery like the facebook mobile app but being able to scroll down the feed anytime I want.

I was thinking about "listening" for side-swypes and replacing the current ImageView but that doesn't sound like an elegant solution.

I searched for awhile and didn't find any library worth using

Is there any library or do you have any idea how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ViewPager` component. 
Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Here are some tutorial that can help you get started:

1) http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.sg/2012/10/viewpager-example-in-android.html

2) http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/

Take a look at: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111822/facebook-style-slider)!

Comment: PS: Amulya, do you know how to add a ViewPager programatically?

Comment: @Amulya really nice answer. But can you please let me know what should i have to do if i want to look it exactly same as facebook slider? I mean the previous and next image should be display as it is displaying in the question.