# PageTransformer'd VerticalViewPager: How to get partial view of next page?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In short: How to get [this effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907748/viewpager-get-a-partial-view-of-the-next-page) (but vertical) while using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797619/1034042)?

There is no `getPageHeight`. Using `getPageWidth` returning 0.9f gives the effect that all pages are more narrow, and the 2nd one shows a part of the 1st at the top... but shifted to the left.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this? I'm working on the same requirement.

Comment: @codeyourstack Nope. Arranged a small circus where designer changed it to something easier, and we (devs) praised it in front of the decision-maker.

Comment: Oh. Okay I was able to achieve it to some extent but have got nested scroll view inside it so it's giving me random behavior now. Without scrollview inside view pager pages it's working fine.