# How to make the second item of recyclerView visible 20% of the view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a CustomView that is a LinearLayout where it contains

TextView
RecyclerView
TheRecyclerViewItem

That's because I need to do something like this :

[image]

The first picture it works fine, but when trying to populate the list with more items, it gets the size of the Item and I'd like to make it a bit smaller so I can see in the screen the second item, otherwise the list only have visible one item at once, and that's normal because I'm using the same view for the item of recycler view than my first image, but I didn't want to duplicate layout, if that's the only solution I'll do it, but I'm trying to figure it out a "better" solution than duplicating and make it a different width.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653406/make-width-of-horizontal-recycler-view-items-70-of-screen-width) the effect you are looking for?