# Showing two screen on single page using ViewPager

Tags: android

I am trying to show two screen using single page by using ViewPager

Here is my xml Part named as **login**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dip"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <com.medmainfomatix.VoIPvoiceapp.MyViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerVertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout_sms"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:digits="1234567890">

                <requestFocus />

            </EditText>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_request_sms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layout_otp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/otptext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/otptext1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputOtp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              >

                <requestFocus />

            </EditText>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.medmainfomatix.VoIPvoiceapp.MyViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my java Activity file named as **LoginActivity** :

```
public class abc extends BaseActivity implements SinchService.StartFailedListener,View.OnClickListener {

    private static String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private PrefManager pref;
    private Button mLoginButton,btnRequestSms;
    private EditText mLoginNo,inputOtp;
    private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private CheckBox mBox;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private TextView otptext;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        createDatabase();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerVertical);
        mBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        otptext= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.otptext);
        inputOtp=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputOtp);
        String checkBoxText = "I agree to all the <a href='http://www.redbus.in/mob/mTerms.aspx' > Terms and Conditions</a>";

        mBox.setText(Html.fromHtml(checkBoxText));
        pref = new PrefManager(this);
        mBox.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        btnRequestSms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_request_sms);
        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        mBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mBox.isChecked()){
                    btnRequestSms.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else{

                    btnRequestSms.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        btnRequestSms.setOnClickListener(this);
        mLoginNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginNo);
        mLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Checking for user session
        // if user is already logged in, take him to main activity
         if (pref.isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PlaceCallActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
        }
        if (pref.isWaitingForSms()) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        }

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_request_sms:
                validateForm();

                break;

            case R.id.loginButton:
                verifyOtp();
                loginClicked();
                break;

        }
    }

    private void loginClicked() {
        String userName = mLoginNo.getText().toString();

        if (userName.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }


    }

    private void openPlaceCallActivity() {
        Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, abc2.class);
        startActivity(mainActivity);
    }  
private void requestForSMS(final String mobile) {
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_REQUEST_SMS, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);

                // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object
                boolean error = responseObj.getBoolean("error");
                String message = responseObj.getString("message");

                // checking for error, if not error SMS is initiated
                // device should receive it shortly
                if (!error) {
                    // boolean flag saying device is waiting for sms
                    pref.setIsWaitingForSms(true);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // hiding the progress bar


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {

        /**
         * Passing user parameters to our server
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("mobile", mobile);

            Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((View) object);
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    resId = R.id.layout_sms;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    resId = R.id.layout_otp;
                    break;
            }
            return findViewById(resId);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **MyViewPager** class :

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public MyViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you are not getting anything please comment because i have cut most of my code and maybe by mistake I mistakenly cutted something related to MyViewPager so please feel free to comment so that i could edit my code and you could get more clear idea else if you are already getting then you can understand what I am trying to achieve here

**GOAL :** To request otp to mobile and the verify otp should come to next screen while request part is gone

Comment: You can't really get "two pages", but you can see the "next & previous" ones. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907748/viewpager-get-a-partial-view-of-the-next-page

Comment: once you send an OTP to device you will receive a callback stating 'success',then yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(1); this will move to next screen.

Comment: @RushiAyyappa Ok so what is this setCurrentItem is doing exactly i am little confused with and what if i set 0 instead of 1

Comment: you are holding an adapter that has fragments with layouts neede for send OTP and verify otp. now viewpager can swipe automatically by setting setCurrentItem(). here if you want to move to next fragment just give it's index i.e 1. initially currentItem is 0 for send OTP.

Comment: lemme try and comeback to you again to convey the results. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @RushiAyyappa Hey though i am getting the otp but still view pager isn't working after clicking on the button i am stuck with first screen only i don't get what is happening earlier also it happened the same thing but some error like Failure getting entry for 0x01080279 (t=7 e=633) (error -75) error for different time value is seen in my logcat. Please help!

Comment: can you post your code where you have written that code

Comment: @RushiAyyappa see i have added the part where i am setting current item to 1 see method requestforsms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129233/discussion-between-sameerkhan1406-and-rushi-ayyappa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you send an OTP to device you will receive a callback stating 'success',then yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(1); this will move to next screen

```
if (!error) {
                    // boolean flag saying device is waiting for sms
                    pref.setIsWaitingForSms(true);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);//this will move to next screen.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Comment: Great it's Working. Thanks alot